# Collecting shapefiles from different users - any rules for quality data/quality control?

Tags: gis, shapefile, qgis

Apologies in advance for this very basic question!

My company collects market information from forestry projects in an annual survey. This year, we are trying to add a spatial element to our analysis. The current plan is to ask survey respondents to upload a shapefile of their project.

My question is: if we collect all of these shapefile responses from individual companies, will there be any difficulties in merging them into a single global map? Ex: do we need to make sure that each shapefile is set to the same projection? Or is there something else I need to check for quality control?

I don't know much about shapefiles or GIS, so I'm worried that I might not think of a basic question to ensure quality data. Right now, I'm planning on the survey saying "Please upload a shapefile (.shp) of your forest project here". Is that okay?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: by 'merging' you mean representing? sure you can do this. the easy part is that combining and manipulating shapes can be easy. you possibly don't know that much about the client-side expertise with gis and spatial data, and this may be a problem. you should ask for a standard format, but also provide your clients with a 'how to do' document, and ask for a specific format (kml) or projection (wgs84 lat lon).

Comment: Yes, I mean representing. You're right, I don't have much client-side expertise, but hopefully we will hire someone by that time. I just wanted to make sure I don't mess anything up for the future person with my questions in the meantime! 

So specific format + project -- thanks!!